# Godot _on_Area2D_area_entered not detecting

Tags: godot

In my Scene I have a Node2D. I then Instanced the Player and Area2D nodes. The Area2D has a signal pointing to itself that prints test when run.

Here is the Code For the Area2D. Nothing happens when an object enters the Area2D.

```
extends Area2D

# Declare member variables here. Examples:
# var a = 2
# var b = "text"

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
#func _process(delta):
#   pass


func _on_Area2D_area_entered(area):
    print('test')
```

Level Scene
[image]

Player
[image]

Area 2D
[image]

Google Drive Link to Project:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OG3BBqKJzC3Je_r5eQdqiFUp7PzzBmt1?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't entirely clear on *what* you want to trigger the signal, but I assume you want it to fire when the player enters the area. The [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_area2d.html#signals) for `area_entered` say:

> Emitted when another area enters.

The player is a `PhysicsBody`, not an `Area`. Use `body_entered` instead:

> Emitted when a physics body enters.
>
> The body argument can either be a PhysicsBody2D or a TileMap instance (while TileMaps are not physics body themselves, they register their tiles with collision shapes as a virtual physics body).